# How to filter for no marker set in log4j2?

Tags: java, log4j2

I want to configure log4j2 in such a way that all messages without a marker are logged. All messages with a marker should only be logged if there is a special ACCEPT rule for this marker in the config file.

I didn't find any filter rule that can detect the "no marker set" case. Is there any or do I have to implement that myself?

The filter part of a log4j2 config might look like the following example, but the *NoMarkerFilter* statement should catch the case that no marker is set.

```
<Filters>
        <MarkerFilter marker="SQL_UPDATE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
        <NoMarkerFilter onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
</Filters>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update - July, 2019**

NoMarkerFilter is shipped as a part of log4j from [version 2.12.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.12.0)

With this, just the below configuration will work:

```
<Filters>
        <MarkerFilter marker="SQL_UPDATE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
        <NoMarkerFilter onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
</Filters>
```

---

---

I ran into a similar issue and could not find any such implementation available with log4j2. Had to implement one myself.

```
@Plugin(name = "NoMarkerFilter", category = Node.CATEGORY, elementType = Filter.ELEMENT_TYPE, printObject = true)
public class NoMarkerFilter extends AbstractFilter {


  private NoMarkerFilter(final Result onMatch, final Result onMismatch) {
    super(onMatch, onMismatch);
  }

  @Override
  public Result filter(final Logger logger, final Level level, final Marker marker, final String msg,
                       final Object... params) {
    return filter(marker);
  }

  @Override
  public Result filter(final Logger logger, final Level level, final Marker marker, final Object msg,
                       final Throwable t) {
    return filter(marker);
  }

  @Override
  public Result filter(final Logger logger, final Level level, final Marker marker, final Message msg,
                       final Throwable t) {
    return filter(marker);
  }

  @Override
  public Result filter(final LogEvent event) {
    return filter(event.getMarker());
  }

  @Override
  public Result filter(final Logger logger, final Level level, final Marker marker, final String msg,
                       final Object p0) {
    return filter(marker);
  }

  @Override
  public Result filter(final Logger logger, final Level level, final Marker marker, final String msg,
                       final Object p0, final Object p1) {
    return filter(marker);
  }

  @Override
  public Result filter(final Logger logger, final Level level, final Marker marker, final String msg,
                       final Object p0, final Object p1, final Object p2) {
    return filter(marker);
  }

  @Override
  public Result filter(final Logger logger, final Level level, final Marker marker, final String msg,
                       final Object p0, final Object p1, final Object p2, final Object p3) {
    return filter(marker);
  }

  @Override
  public Result filter(final Logger logger, final Level level, final Marker marker, final String msg,
                       final Object p0, final Object p1, final Object p2, final Object p3,
                       final Object p4) {
    return filter(marker);
  }

  @Override
  public Result filter(final Logger logger, final Level level, final Marker marker, final String msg,
                       final Object p0, final Object p1, final Object p2, final Object p3,
                       final Object p4, final Object p5) {
    return filter(marker);
  }

  @Override
  public Result filter(final Logger logger, final Level level, final Marker marker, final String msg,
                       final Object p0, final Object p1, final Object p2, final Object p3,
                       final Object p4, final Object p5, final Object p6) {
    return filter(marker);
  }

  @Override
  public Result filter(final Logger logger, final Level level, final Marker marker, final String msg,
                       final Object p0, final Object p1, final Object p2, final Object p3,
                       final Object p4, final Object p5, final Object p6,
                       final Object p7) {
    return filter(marker);
  }

  @Override
  public Result filter(final Logger logger, final Level level, final Marker marker, final String msg,
                       final Object p0, final Object p1, final Object p2, final Object p3,
                       final Object p4, final Object p5, final Object p6,
                       final Object p7, final Object p8) {
    return filter(marker);
  }

  @Override
  public Result filter(final Logger logger, final Level level, final Marker marker, final String msg,
                       final Object p0, final Object p1, final Object p2, final Object p3,
                       final Object p4, final Object p5, final Object p6,
                       final Object p7, final Object p8, final Object p9) {
    return filter(marker);
  }

  private Result filter(final Marker marker) {
    return null == marker ? onMatch : onMismatch;
  }

  /**
   * Create the NoMarkerFilter.
   *
   * @param match    The action to take if a match occurs.
   * @param mismatch The action to take if no match occurs.
   * @return A NoMarkerFilter.
   */
  @PluginFactory
  public static NoMarkerFilter createFilter(
      @PluginAttribute("onMatch") final Result match,
      @PluginAttribute("onMismatch") final Result mismatch) {
    return new NoMarkerFilter(match, mismatch);
  }
}
```

With this, the below configuration should work:

```
<Filters>
        <MarkerFilter marker="SQL_UPDATE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
        <NoMarkerFilter onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
</Filters>
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!